# Fortify Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration with MultipartFormDataInput

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, fortify

We have Fortify Critical issues “Mass Assignment : Insecure Binder Configuration” .

The issue is related to using a REST service which consume a MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.

Fortify is complaining about multipartFormDataInput object.
Any advice please about fixing this?

Comment: Thanks Vasan but I'm not using Spring MVC here and my issue is when using multipartFormDataInput object which is a resteasy interface

Comment: I see - but the same principles should still apply - whitelisting / blacklisting to filter out harmful fields..

Comment: I was searching solution for same fortify mass assignment issue,  whitelisting and black listing is a tedious task for my application.Is there any other way to fix this other than spring Data binder?